# One taxonomy with tree

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

## update

I want to create one taxonomy Period: In this taxonomy there must multiple terms in it. a term year and in term year there are values (1 bachelor, 2 bachelor,.. 1 master, 2 master). and another term "training" (nurse, medecine,... industrial science). and 2 other therms training days, tion rights graduation with values in it.
How can I do the previous in one Taxonomy, in Drupal 6. Thanks!

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new *vocabulary* at `admin/content/taxonomy/add/vocabulary` and name it "Period" and choose which content types you want to use it with.
2. You will be directed back to the taxonomy page, click on the *"Add Terms"* link for the vocabulary "Period"
3. Add all "terms" and "values" you want (year, 1 bachelor, 2 bachelor, 1 master, 2 master, training, nurse, etc) on the *"Add Terms"* page for the "Period" vocabulary
4. Click on the list items tab and rearrange the terms however you like. For instance: To make "1 bachelor" a child (value) for "Year", move "1 bachelor" under "Year" and drag it to the right.

Your *"List Terms"* page should look similar to this (with all additional terms you want added):
[image: Example Taxonomy Vocabulary]

Here are some links about to learn more about Drupal Taxonomy:
[Drupal Taxonomy Overview](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy)
[Understanding taxonomies for new users](http://drupal.org/node/46268)
[Drupal Taxonomy (VIDEO)](http://www.powerfulcms.com/cms-taxonomy)
[How To: Leverage Drupal Taxonomy (VIDEO)](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-taxonomy)
[Taxonomy Overview (VIDEO)](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/79)

Comment: @yannick no problem, I added links to learn more about Drupal Taxonomy as well